# Compiling multiple Coq files does not work

Tags: coq

I'm really lost on how to actually use multiple files in Coq. I was trying to follow [these directions](https://blog.zhen-zhang.com/2016/09/19/coq-dev.html).

I have two files.

`src/a.v`:

```
Definition bar: nat := 1.
```

`src/b.v`:

```
Require Import a.

Definition foo := bar.
```

I attempt to compile as such:

`coqc -R src "" src/a.v src/b.v`

I get the following error:

```
user@machine:~/code/coq$ coqc -R src "" src/a.v src/b.v
While loading initial state:
Loading file /home/user/code/coq/src/.b.aux: aux file name mismatch
```

I can't find any clear information on how you actually compile with multiple files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend you perform two calls to `coqc`, first with `a` then with `b`. Having multiple files in the argument command line is actually not supported [we will improve the interface in next versions as to warn about this]